# error en input tipo date

Tags: php, html, date

he estado probando muchas maneras de hacer coincidir un input tipo date con datos de una tabla.
Ahora tengo esto en index.html

```
<form action="consultas/consulta1_fecha_despacho.php" method="post">
Fecha:
<input type="date" name="fecha" >
<br/><br/>
<input type="submit" value="Buscar">
```

Y en PHP

```
<?php
#Llama a conexión, crea el objeto PDO y obtiene la variable $db
require("../config/conexion.php");

#Se obtiene el valor del input del usuario
$fecha = $_POST["fecha"];

$query = "SELECT c.nombre, c.calle, c.numero_domicilio, c.comuna, c.region
FROM Compras co
JOIN Clientes c ON co.id_cliente = c.id
WHERE co.fecha_entrega = $fecha;";
$result = $db -> prepare($query);
$result -> execute();
$datos_compra = $result -> fetchAll();
?>
```

El problema es que no imprime nada. Se que el formato de compras.fecha_entrega es "Y-m-d" y es tipo date y deberia funcionar lo que tengo porque creo que el tipe date en el input guarda en ese mismo formato, he probado strtotype, date_create, date_format y nada me funciona.

Comment: Hola. ¿Qué muestra un `var_dump($_POST);` puesto al inicio de tu script PHP? ¿Has verificado que realmente existen registros con esa fecha en la base de datos? ¿De qué tipo es la columna `fecha_entrega`? Aunque tampoco veo que imprimas nada en el código PHP de la pregunta.

Answer (score 1):

Si la fecha te llega así: `"2003-10-18"` es un formato válido, pero es una cadena, por lo que tendrías que cambiar el `WHERE` de este modo:

```
... WHERE co.fecha_entrega = '$fecha';
```

O sea, rodear la variable `$fecha` de comillas simples `'`. Ese simple cambio corregiría tu código actual.

Pero aún hay más, y se trata de un problema que atañe a la seguridad de los datos. Dejar esa consulta funcionando así sería una puerta abierta a ataques de *inyección SQL* (cuando puedas lee sobre el tema), deberías usar consultas preparadas **reales**, cosa que aquí no haces, aunque uses `prepare()`.

Deberías también verificar el estado del POST antes de pasar a usar los datos.

Aplicando lo dicho, el código quedaría así:

```
<?php

    #Se obtiene el valor del input del usuario
    $fecha = $_POST["fecha"] ?? null;
    if( isset($fecha) ) {      
        #Llama a conexión, crea el objeto PDO y obtiene la variable $db
        require("../config/conexion.php"); 
        /*
           En vez de la variable $fecha
           ponemos un marcador :fecha para
           evitar Inyección SQL
           La variable la pasaremos con bindParam
           más adelante
        */                      
        $query = "SELECT c.nombre, c.calle, c.numero_domicilio, c.comuna, c.region
        FROM Compras co
        JOIN Clientes c ON co.id_cliente = c.id
        WHERE co.fecha_entrega = :fecha;";
        $result = $db -> prepare($query);
        #Esto evitará ataques de Inyección SQL
        $result->bindParam(':fecha',$fecha,PDO::PARAM_STR);
        $result -> execute();
        $datos_compra = $result -> fetchAll();
    } else {
        echo "No se envió ninguna fecha";
    }

?>
```

Así debería funcionar, salvo otros errores fuera de nuestro alcance, como que la columna sea de otro tipo en la base de datos...

Una herramienta para validar si la fecha es válida sería intentar crear un objeto `DateTime` a partir de `$fecha`. En algunos SGBD, como SQL Server por ejemplo, sería de gran utilidad, porque el SGBD espera/devuelve un objeto de este tipo en caso de columnas `DATE` o `DATETIME`

Answer (score 0):

Creo que el problema podría residir en como te está llegando el dato fecha del formulario. En este caso la fecha que el usuario introduce en el formulario llegará de la siguiente manera: xx/xx/xxxx, es decir, con " / " y luego estás buscando en base de datos una fecha con " / " cuando realmente el formato de fecha en la tabla de BD está en formato " - ", es decir: "Y-m-d".

La solución sería que hicieses un format de la variable $fecha del php y transformarla a " - " eliminando así las " / ".

Un saludo

Comment: quizas sea eso, pensaba que del form llegaba en formato aaaa-mm-dd

Comment: Si haces un var_dump($fecha) podrás asegurarte al 100% de como llega.

Comment: Se puede cambiar el formato de $fecha en el php? como me recomiendas hacerlo?

Comment: hice echo var_dump($fecha) y me retorno esto string(10) "2003-10-18"

Comment: y te arroja algún error la consola del navegador cuando envías el formulario? en caso de que te dé un error cuál es?; y sino te devuelve ningún error igual el problema podría estar en los datos de la tabla y que no tengas registros para las fechas que estás introduciendo.

Comment: @Pamela Si la fecha te llega así: `"2003-10-18"` es un formato válido, pero es una cadena, por lo que tienes que cambiar el `WHERE` de este modo: **`WHERE co.fecha_entrega = '$fecha';`** , o sea, rodear la variable `$fecha` de comillas simples `'`. De todos modos, esa consulta no es segura, deberías usar consultas preparadas **reales**, cosa que aquí no haces, aunque uses `prepare()`
.

Answer (score 0):

Lo resolvi simplemente poniendo '$fecha' en la línea

```
WHERE co.fecha_entrega = '$fecha';";
```

Gracias por ayudar igualmente!

Comment: No obstante, ese código no es seguro, deberías usar consultas preparadas.